# JYaml: dump object without including class name

Tags: java, yaml, jyaml

I have an `ArrayList` of objects being dumped to a YAML string and have been comparing the performance of JYaml and SnakeYaml in handling this.

```
    ArrayList<HashMap> testList = new ArrayList<HashMap>();
    HashMap<String, String> testMap1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    HashMap<String, String> testMap2 = new HashMap<String, String>();

    testMap1.put("1_1", "One");
    testMap1.put("1_2", "Two");
    testMap1.put("1_3", "Three");

    testMap2.put("2_1", "One");
    testMap2.put("2_2", "Two");
    testMap2.put("2_3", "Three");

    testList.add(testMap1);
    testList.add(testMap2);

    System.out.println(jYaml.dump(testList));
    System.out.println(snakeYaml.dump(testList));
```

The output from JYaml includes the serialised object's class name whereas the output from SnakeYaml does not:

JYaml output:

```
- !java.util.HashMap
  1_1: One
  1_3: Three
  1_2: Two
- !java.util.HashMap
  2_1: One
  2_2: Two
  2_3: Three
```

SnakeYaml output:

```
- {'1_1': One, '1_3': Three, '1_2': Two}
- {'2_1': One, '2_2': Two, '2_3': Three}
```

I prefer the more 'clean' class name-less output of SnakeYaml as this would be more suitable for a language-neutral environment.

I prefer the *speed* of JYaml. Serialisation/deserialisation times increase *linearly* with the amount of data being processed, as opposed to  *exponentially* with SnakeYaml.

I'd like to coerce JYaml into giving me class name-less output but am quite lost as to how this can be achieved.

Comment: Why not to create a ticket in SnakeYAML? (http://trac-hg.assembla.com/snakeyaml/report/1)
Once the problem with performance is reported and identified it can be fixed.
SnakeYAML's output is very flexible. Check http://instantyaml.appspot.com/ (login to see the options)

Comment: The problem is identified: regular expressions do not scale in SnakeYAML. JYaml does not use regular expressions to find the proper type at all. (scalar is always a String in JYaml). It is possible to follow the same approach in SnakeYAML. Is it what you expect?

Comment: @andrey: Thanks for pointing that out. I'm now more curious: is the use of regular expressions, in the way you explain, required such that /any/ well-written dumper/loader would exhibit the same performance issues?

Comment: @andrey: "It is possible to follow the same approach in SnakeYAML. Is it what you expect?". Sorry, you lost me a bit there. What is it you're asking?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Check the SnakeYAML latest source. [It is now possible](http://trac-hg.assembla.com/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation#ImplicitTypes) (same as in JYaml) to ignore implicit typing and always parse scalars as Strings. This is a few times faster.
Look [here](http://trac-hg.assembla.com/snakeyaml/browser/src/test/java/org/yaml/snakeyaml/StressTest.java) and [here](http://trac-hg.assembla.com/snakeyaml/browser/src/test/java/org/yaml/snakeyaml/NoRegularExpressionsTest.java) to see how to use the new feature.

(With the RegularExpressions off serialisation/deserialisation times increase linearly with the amount of data being processed.)

Comment: -1 this doesn't include the answer for how to get jyaml to not include the class names.  That's what I came here for.

Comment: all the links are dead.

Comment: link are dead , links are not good way to answer , write your answers here so it will not be dead

Answer (score -1):

How do you measure the speed ? What do you mean 'amount of data' ? Is it a size of a YAML document or an amount of documents ?

JYaml output is **incorrect**. According to the specification underscores in numbers are ignored and 1_1 = 11 (at least for YAML 1.1). Because it is in fact a String and not an Integer the representation shall be:

- '1_1': One

or canonically

- !!str "1_1": !!str "One"

Otherwise when the document is parsed it will create Map<**Integer**, String> instead of Map<**String**, String>

JYaml has many open issues and does not implement complete YAML 1.1

JYaml may indeed be faster but it is due to the simplified parsing and emitting.